# IndexedDB - new version of database

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

My PWA uses IndexedDB to store Data.

Now im releasing Version 2.0 for it, which requires the storing of data in a third ObjectStore.

When the PWA was first released, the IndexedDB created had the version "1" like this.

```
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("database-db", 1);

// Creating ObjectStores
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;

    var driverTable = db.createObjectStore("driver");
    var claimTable = db.createObjectStore("claim", {
        autoIncrement: "true"
    });
};
```

For the Release of 2.0 i now went ahead and created another ObjectStore (language) in my "onupgradeneeded" handler and changed the version like this, hoping the IndexedDB would automatically reload itself with the new version in the background.

```
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("database-db", 2);

// Creating ObjectStores
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;

    var languageTable = db.createObjectStore("language");
    var driverTable = db.createObjectStore("driver");
    var claimTable = db.createObjectStore("claim", {
        autoIncrement: "true"
    });
};
```

Unfortunately this only works for 2 scenarios.

1. I open the PWA in Chrome on my desktop and delete the IndexedDB in the Application-Tab of DevTools and  reload the page afterwards.
2. I never opened the site before and therefore have no IndexedDB installed in my browser.

The problem is, that i already have existing users and they have no option of deleting the IndexedDB on their smartphones, apart from that not being an option in terms of user-experience.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also see: https://web.dev/indexeddb/#versioning

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are better ways to approach this. You can do version number based checks, or just check if things exist or not. Here is some simple example code that checks if a store exists and only creates a store if it does not exist.

```js
function myOnUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  const db = event.target.result;

  if (db.objectStoreNames.contains('mystorename') {
    console.log('mystorename already exists, not recreating');
  } else {
    console.log('mystorename does not exist,  creating');
    db.createObjectStore('mystorename');
  }
}
```

If you want to remove all objects from a store on upgrade, then you can add logic that says that if the table exists, you can clear it.

Comment: This is good if all DB features are already known. But what if you decide to add an index to a DB once you update to v2? And another index once you start working with a version 3 of you IndexedDB?

Comment: Then you check if the index exists. See my many other answers to similar questions of which this question is basically a duplicate

Comment: Yes, I am reading through stackoverflow's indexeddb questions. However, a good walkthrough on how to build and keep a proper migration path seems to be missing. – Let's say I have v9, and I once added an index to a store (e.g. in v4), but later removed it (e.g. in v7). When I call the app in a new browser, it opens v9 directly. How can I make sure the updates are called in proper order? Laravel uses dates. I wonder if that's the right way to go (still early stages). How do you approach such a szenario?

Comment: Use a combination of checking the old version property and the connection version property. Create a series of migration functions for each version to version. On connect, iterate through the various migration functions. Keep in mind you cannot await.